# Codeception grabRecord failing

Tags: yii2, codeception

Using Yii2 2.0.12, php 5.6.24 and codeception 2.3.3

On a recent upgrade a set of acceptance tests that have always worked up to now, failed. The upgrade was a standard composer update to the latest versions. The test scenario is as follows:

- Test adding a record via a form
- Grab the new record to verify
- Test adding a second record via a form
- Grab the new record to verify

The second grab fails in that it returns an empty record. I've traced this back to the 'queryInternal' method of the 'Command' object and there is a correctly formed PDO statement which performs the correct query but returns an empty result. I've tried breaking before the PDO->execute() and performing the query in MySQL. The query works but the PDO statement fails.

the code of the Cept test script is:

```
$I->wantTo('Do successive grabs');

$I->amOnPage('index.php?r=portfolio%2Fcreate');
$I->see('Create Portfolio');
$I->fillField('Name','Test Portfolio 1');
$I->click('Create');
$r = $I->grabRecord('app\models\Portfolio' , ['name' => 'Test Portfolio 1']);


$I->amOnPage('index.php?r=portfolio%2Fcreate');
$I->see('Create Portfolio');
$I->fillField('Name','Test Portfolio 2');
$I->click('Create');
$r = $I->grabRecord('app\models\Portfolio' , ['name' => 'Test Portfolio 2']);
```

The second "grabRecord" produces an empty record. Anyone else have a similar problem?

Comment: Github is a better place to report issues: https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been caused by the change in the 'cleanup' option in 2.2.6. Changing this value to false in the .yml file seems to clear the problem, although I'm not sure why.